# How to disable first link in dropdown menu (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have a menu in my CMS which is controlled programatically and I don't have access to the code, the only thing I can add is js/jquery. I would like to disable the first element from the menu, ie replace the current href with #. I'm new to jquery and need some help. Here's a menu sample.

```
<nav class="main-nav">
<div class="shell">
<ul>
<li class="taphover">
<a href="/education">Education &amp; Training<i class="ico-arrow"></i></a>
<div class="dd">
<ul>
<li><a href="/educators-students/field-trip">Book a Field Trip</a></li>
<li><a href="/educator-development">Educator Development</a></li>
<li><a href="/specialized-student-programs">Specialized Student Programs</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

I'd like to replace /education with #. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
//select the first anchor where href="/education"
var anchor = $("a[href='/education']")[0];

//change the href of the anchor
anchor.attr('href') = "#";
```

Comment: Thanks! This might work. I have multiple menus though, I was hoping for a less manual way to do this, instead of selecting each anchor, is there a way to replace all anchors inside the taphover class?

Comment: I think $(".taphover a") will select all anchors within a taphover tag. Check out https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp for a good rundown of jQuery selectors.